# Ubuntu Cloud Internet Sources Needed for Network Whitelist

Tags: internet, juju, maas, cloud, openstack

We are attempting to deploy Ubuntu Cloud Openstack Juno with MAAS and need to determine each Internet endpoint that Ubuntu Cloud needs to connect to from the LAN.  Each destination needs to be white listed and categorized or we are unable to access them.

While the Ubuntu Cloud installation instructions provide a list or additional Apt repositories, there is no mention of what Juju needs access to in the Internet, or anything else that is not in the repository list.

Netstat outputs for the locations I have managed to catch already:

```
root@hostname:~# netstat -untap | grep 443
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.x:49128     91.189.89.222:443       SYN_SENT    57117/python3
root@hostname:~# netstat -untap | grep 443
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.x:44643     91.189.89.223:443       SYN_SENT    57026/python3
```

How can I find the rest?

Comment: This has not been answered still.  Is there a list of required packages somewhere that maybe I could track down the sources from, then map those back to ip addresses for specifi mirrors maybe?  Thanks.